# Генерация чисел по заданной маске

Tags: python

Есть функция get_rand_0_255(), которая генерирует случайное число в диапазоне от 0 до 255.
Есть еще одна функция get_ip(), которая должна генерировать ip адресс по заданному шаблону mask.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно написать функцию get_ip()?

```
from random import randint


def get_rand_0_255():
    return randint(0, 255)


def get_ip(mask="xxx.xx.xx.x"):
    mask_list = mask.split('.')
    ip_parts = []
# Неизвестный блок кода

return ".".join(ip_parts)
```

Comment: а что вы понимаете под шаблоном маски? как это выглядит и что означает?

Comment: xxx.xx.xx.x - вот например по этому шаблону. 3 цифры.2 цифры.2 цифры.1 цифра. Как в переменной mask. При том, что ее можно задать как угодно

Comment: тогда генерируйте от 0 до 255, когда надо 2 цифры - делайте `rnd % 100`, а когда 1, то `rnd % 10`, или генерируйте в нужных диапазонах только после того как маску распарсите

Comment: Как это правильно записать, подскажите, пожалуйста. И я так понимаю, что функция get_rand_0_255() в случае, когда есть маска, бесполезна?

Comment: не бесполезна, но избыточна - используйте `randint` И задавайте диапазон

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно так:

```
from random import randint

def gen_subnet(digit_length=2):
    stop = 256 if digit_length > 2 else 10**digit_length
    start = 10**(digit_length-1)
    return randint(start, stop)
    

def gen_ip(mask="xxx.xx.xx.x"):
    return ".".join([str(gen_subnet(len(x))) for x in mask.split(".")])


print(gen_ip()) # 217.26.64.1
```

Comment: Спасибо. и у вас такая же проблема. может сгенерировать и однозначное число. Как сделать ограничение?

Comment: Переделал. так устроит?

Answer (score 0):

Ну вот так наверное:

```
from random import randint

def get_rand_0_255():
    return randint(0, 255)

def get_ip(mask="xxx.xx.xx.x"):
    mask_list = mask.split('.')
    ip_parts = [str(get_rand_0_255())[:len(m)] for m in mask_list]
    return ".".join(ip_parts)

print(get_ip())
```

Ну то есть обрезаем сгенерированное число по размеру маски.

Comment: Спасибо. есть небольшая проблема. в первом оно может сгенерировать и двухзначное число так же как и в следующих - однозначное. Как это ограничить?